# How do you insert an Excel sheet as part of a new mail message?

Tags: gmail, microsoft-excel

I tried inserting a MS Excel document directly / via a Microsoft document but when copied into a new Gmail message the formatting wasn't retained.

How do you insert an Excel sheet as part of a new mail message?

Comment: How do I fit a square peg into a round hole? It's incompatible formats. GMail doesn't support tables & spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

As Gmail doesn't preserve formatting, your options may be to:

- Copy the file to Google Drive and reference that using the "Insert
  files using Drive" option
- Insert a screenshot of the relevant portion
  of the sheet within the email, if you're particular about formatting
  and the data isn't a lot

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an editable sheet? If not Excel can save as PDF or as a webpage to maintain the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Copy what you want from the Excel document to MS Word first, and then try to paste it into Gmail by coping it from MS Word.